# How to Update List[index] When Tab Key is Pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a script that receives a List of game object. When I press the tab key, the script must update the `index` by 1 (`index++`), get the `gameobject` in that position, then log the name of the `gameobject`, this is the piece of code for the script

```cs
void Start() {
  index = 0;
}

void Update(){
  ChangeLeader();
}

void ChangeLeader(){
  if (index >= playerList.Count){
    index = 0;
  }else{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab)){
      leader = playerList[index];
      index += 1;
      Debug.Log(leader.name);
    }
  }
}
```

What I was expecting was that every time I press tab, it will log the objects name then updates the `index` in 1 unit.

The problem is that I was expecting the code to log all the names in the List at once.

It don't feel discouraged to call me dumb. I only started with unity a few days ago, thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide what playerlist type is and more over how you populated it

Answer (score 0):

`Update()` is called every frame.
`(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))` is gonna be `true` for consecutive frames, because your finger is down for a few milliseconds.

Use:
`(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))`
or
`(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Tab))` instead. This is triggered just once.